# Dbpedia search with SPARQL

Tags: dbpedia

I have a problem with SPARQL on dbpedia. I want to collect some data from diffrent kinds of animals and I thought it would be a good idea to use dbpedia, but I don't really understand how it works. I watched a video on youtube and after that I still dont really get it.

My question is now, for example, I want to search for all the frogs (or any kind of animal) and I want it to return with the Kingdom, Phylum, class, order, family, genus and species (these are in the infoboxes). How do I write the line of code?

I saw another post and his solution to get all the movies Tom Hanks played in was this (below), but when I try to search for example here: http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/Amphibian then I don't see anything I can use.

```
SELECT ?f     
WHERE {
?f rdf:type dbo:Film .
?f dbo:starring dbr:Tom_Hanks .
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead dbpedia, you can use [Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/).
It has nice [tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual) and by my opinion it's better than dbpedia.

For example this query with movies, where Tom Hanks played (including description and director info):

```
  SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?directorLabel WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
  ?item wdt:P161 wd:Q2263 .
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P57 ?director .} 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

You can try it yourself [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20%3FdirectorLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP161%20wd%3AQ2263%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP57%20%3Fdirector%20.%7D%20%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A).

Comment: Thanks alot! i got it working. 

But there is something else now. I can only ask for a few things to get in the results, and not everything thats in the infoboxes on wikipedia. Am i doing something wrong or is this the limitation of using this site? 

For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius

is it possible to ask for the whole infobox from a star like this and maybe the first 5-10 lines?

Comment: you can get everything, what contains here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3409, for example following properties: constellation, Commons category and so on. Not sure about infobox.

Comment: infoboxes are just format of information from Wikidata, which actually fields and you can get values of these fields using Wikidata query.

Comment: There is no 1 to 1 correspondence between Wikidata and Wikipedia infoboxes (and transitively DBpedia). There can be an overlap in many cases but each dataset can have a lot more information